# Search documents contents using SharePoint 2013 REST API or CSOM

Tags: 2013, search, asp.net, client-object-model, rest

I'm wondering if there is a way to query the actual contents of the document using the REST API or using the CSOM and CAML from an ASP.NET application?  I remember in a previous job that we used FAST search to accomplish this but it seems that FAST has been integrated into the search in 2013?

I've done some searching around but haven't found anything they tells me in black and white... It looks like simply using the querytext filter might do it?

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using SharePoint 2013 REST Search API does search the contents of documents (including PDF) out of the box. There are a couple way to do this but the simplest for a GET is:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='sharepoint'
```

You can add a ton of additional terms and query modifiers, but that is the essence of the request.

Look for more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876(v=office.15).aspx

And here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/search/query?querytext='contenttype:"+cntType+"'&path:'"+startingUrl+"'

Answer (score 0):

I was using [Share .NET](http://www.independentsoft.com/share) in an ASP .NET application. It supports FAST and KQL search and works pretty well. You can try it.

Comment: Thanks! So there is nothing native?